# How many natural numbers less than 200 will have 12 factors/divisors?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> How many natural numbers less than 200 will have 12 factors (a.k.a. divisors)?

I think the answer is $11$.

Firstly there can be at most $3$ distinct prime factors.

$12=1\cdot12
  =2\cdot6
  =3\cdot4
  =2\cdot2\cdot3$

$N=a^{11}
 =a\cdot b^5
 =a^2\cdot b^3
 =a\cdot b\cdot c^2$

Then, $1$ prime factor is not possible because the smallest $2^{11}> 200$. So, the options are:

For $2$ prime factors:
$72, 96, 160$

For $3$ prime factors:
$60,90,150,84,140,126,132,156$.

I think this list is exhaustive. But am I right? Is there any other approach?

Comment: Why did you stop formatting in MathJax in the middle of the question? Also, use `\cdot` to write the multiplication dot.

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you please explain better what are you looking for? For me $2$ is the smallest possible factor in $\Bbb{Z}$, but $2^{12}=4096 > 200$...

Comment: @Ale Say 72=2^3*3^2. Then number of factors of 72=(3+1)*(2+1)=12

Comment: @Ale The question is clearly posed given the [definition of a factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). For example, $72$ has $12$ factors: $1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36,72$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee My bad. I swapped factors with irreducible. Now is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** there are necessarily two factors $a,b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then using the fact that $\tau$ is multiplicative, you must have $\tau(a)\tau(b) = 12$ with $\min(\tau(a), \tau(b)) > 1$. This much simplifies the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? It may sound silly to you but I could not quite understand the hint.

Comment: the solutions have the form $a\times b$ where $(\tau(a), \tau(b)) \in \{ (2,6), (3,4) \}$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. You have some sort of recursion. The subproblems are much easier.

Comment: Nice observation.

Answer (score 6):

I know you guys love your maths (and I do too) but, for something as finite as this (i.e., not something that would consume *years* of compute time), you can test it with an exhaustive computer program, one that takes about three thousandths of a second on my desktop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int quantN[200] = {0};

    for (int number = 1; number < 200; number++) {
        int quant = 0;

        for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= number; divisor++)
            if (number % divisor == 0)
                quant++;

        printf ("%3d: (%2d):", number, quant);
        quantN[quant]++;

        for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= number; divisor++)
            if (number % divisor == 0)
                printf (" %3d", divisor);

        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');
    for (int quant = 0; quant < 200; quant++)
        if (quantN[quant] > 0)
            printf ("Quantity with %2d factors is %d\n",
                quant, quantN[quant]);

    return 0;
}
```

The relevant lines of that output are:

```
 60: (12):   1   2   3   4   5   6  10  12  15  20  30  60
 72: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   8   9  12  18  24  36  72
 84: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   7  12  14  21  28  42  84
 90: (12):   1   2   3   5   6   9  10  15  18  30  45  90
 96: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   8  12  16  24  32  48  96
108: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   9  12  18  27  36  54 108
126: (12):   1   2   3   6   7   9  14  18  21  42  63 126
132: (12):   1   2   3   4   6  11  12  22  33  44  66 132
140: (12):   1   2   4   5   7  10  14  20  28  35  70 140
150: (12):   1   2   3   5   6  10  15  25  30  50  75 150
156: (12):   1   2   3   4   6  12  13  26  39  52  78 156
160: (12):   1   2   4   5   8  10  16  20  32  40  80 160
198: (12):   1   2   3   6   9  11  18  22  33  66  99 198

Quantity with 12 factors is 13
```

The complete output of that is shown below, and I'll ask in advance for forgiveness for butchering the English language with the phrase `"Quantity with 1 factors is 1"` but I don't see the need for making the program grammatically aware for what is, in essence, a one-off activity.

Or you can just take that to mean I'm basically lazy :-)

```
  1: ( 1):   1
  2: ( 2):   1   2
  3: ( 2):   1   3
  4: ( 3):   1   2   4
  5: ( 2):   1   5
  6: ( 4):   1   2   3   6
  7: ( 2):   1   7
  8: ( 4):   1   2   4   8
  9: ( 3):   1   3   9
 10: ( 4):   1   2   5  10
 11: ( 2):   1  11
 12: ( 6):   1   2   3   4   6  12
 13: ( 2):   1  13
 14: ( 4):   1   2   7  14
 15: ( 4):   1   3   5  15
 16: ( 5):   1   2   4   8  16
 17: ( 2):   1  17
 18: ( 6):   1   2   3   6   9  18
 19: ( 2):   1  19
 20: ( 6):   1   2   4   5  10  20
 21: ( 4):   1   3   7  21
 22: ( 4):   1   2  11  22
 23: ( 2):   1  23
 24: ( 8):   1   2   3   4   6   8  12  24
 25: ( 3):   1   5  25
 26: ( 4):   1   2  13  26
 27: ( 4):   1   3   9  27
 28: ( 6):   1   2   4   7  14  28
 29: ( 2):   1  29
 30: ( 8):   1   2   3   5   6  10  15  30
 31: ( 2):   1  31
 32: ( 6):   1   2   4   8  16  32
 33: ( 4):   1   3  11  33
 34: ( 4):   1   2  17  34
 35: ( 4):   1   5   7  35
 36: ( 9):   1   2   3   4   6   9  12  18  36
 37: ( 2):   1  37
 38: ( 4):   1   2  19  38
 39: ( 4):   1   3  13  39
 40: ( 8):   1   2   4   5   8  10  20  40
 41: ( 2):   1  41
 42: ( 8):   1   2   3   6   7  14  21  42
 43: ( 2):   1  43
 44: ( 6):   1   2   4  11  22  44
 45: ( 6):   1   3   5   9  15  45
 46: ( 4):   1   2  23  46
 47: ( 2):   1  47
 48: (10):   1   2   3   4   6   8  12  16  24  48
 49: ( 3):   1   7  49
 50: ( 6):   1   2   5  10  25  50
 51: ( 4):   1   3  17  51
 52: ( 6):   1   2   4  13  26  52
 53: ( 2):   1  53
 54: ( 8):   1   2   3   6   9  18  27  54
 55: ( 4):   1   5  11  55
 56: ( 8):   1   2   4   7   8  14  28  56
 57: ( 4):   1   3  19  57
 58: ( 4):   1   2  29  58
 59: ( 2):   1  59
 60: (12):   1   2   3   4   5   6  10  12  15  20  30  60
 61: ( 2):   1  61
 62: ( 4):   1   2  31  62
 63: ( 6):   1   3   7   9  21  63
 64: ( 7):   1   2   4   8  16  32  64
 65: ( 4):   1   5  13  65
 66: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  11  22  33  66
 67: ( 2):   1  67
 68: ( 6):   1   2   4  17  34  68
 69: ( 4):   1   3  23  69
 70: ( 8):   1   2   5   7  10  14  35  70
 71: ( 2):   1  71
 72: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   8   9  12  18  24  36  72
 73: ( 2):   1  73
 74: ( 4):   1   2  37  74
 75: ( 6):   1   3   5  15  25  75
 76: ( 6):   1   2   4  19  38  76
 77: ( 4):   1   7  11  77
 78: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  13  26  39  78
 79: ( 2):   1  79
 80: (10):   1   2   4   5   8  10  16  20  40  80
 81: ( 5):   1   3   9  27  81
 82: ( 4):   1   2  41  82
 83: ( 2):   1  83
 84: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   7  12  14  21  28  42  84
 85: ( 4):   1   5  17  85
 86: ( 4):   1   2  43  86
 87: ( 4):   1   3  29  87
 88: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  11  22  44  88
 89: ( 2):   1  89
 90: (12):   1   2   3   5   6   9  10  15  18  30  45  90
 91: ( 4):   1   7  13  91
 92: ( 6):   1   2   4  23  46  92
 93: ( 4):   1   3  31  93
 94: ( 4):   1   2  47  94
 95: ( 4):   1   5  19  95
 96: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   8  12  16  24  32  48  96
 97: ( 2):   1  97
 98: ( 6):   1   2   7  14  49  98
 99: ( 6):   1   3   9  11  33  99
100: ( 9):   1   2   4   5  10  20  25  50 100
101: ( 2):   1 101
102: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  17  34  51 102
103: ( 2):   1 103
104: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  13  26  52 104
105: ( 8):   1   3   5   7  15  21  35 105
106: ( 4):   1   2  53 106
107: ( 2):   1 107
108: (12):   1   2   3   4   6   9  12  18  27  36  54 108
109: ( 2):   1 109
110: ( 8):   1   2   5  10  11  22  55 110
111: ( 4):   1   3  37 111
112: (10):   1   2   4   7   8  14  16  28  56 112
113: ( 2):   1 113
114: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  19  38  57 114
115: ( 4):   1   5  23 115
116: ( 6):   1   2   4  29  58 116
117: ( 6):   1   3   9  13  39 117
118: ( 4):   1   2  59 118
119: ( 4):   1   7  17 119
120: (16):   1   2   3   4   5   6   8  10  12  15  20  24  30  40  60 120
121: ( 3):   1  11 121
122: ( 4):   1   2  61 122
123: ( 4):   1   3  41 123
124: ( 6):   1   2   4  31  62 124
125: ( 4):   1   5  25 125
126: (12):   1   2   3   6   7   9  14  18  21  42  63 126
127: ( 2):   1 127
128: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128
129: ( 4):   1   3  43 129
130: ( 8):   1   2   5  10  13  26  65 130
131: ( 2):   1 131
132: (12):   1   2   3   4   6  11  12  22  33  44  66 132
133: ( 4):   1   7  19 133
134: ( 4):   1   2  67 134
135: ( 8):   1   3   5   9  15  27  45 135
136: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  17  34  68 136
137: ( 2):   1 137
138: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  23  46  69 138
139: ( 2):   1 139
140: (12):   1   2   4   5   7  10  14  20  28  35  70 140
141: ( 4):   1   3  47 141
142: ( 4):   1   2  71 142
143: ( 4):   1  11  13 143
144: (15):   1   2   3   4   6   8   9  12  16  18  24  36  48  72 144
145: ( 4):   1   5  29 145
146: ( 4):   1   2  73 146
147: ( 6):   1   3   7  21  49 147
148: ( 6):   1   2   4  37  74 148
149: ( 2):   1 149
150: (12):   1   2   3   5   6  10  15  25  30  50  75 150
151: ( 2):   1 151
152: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  19  38  76 152
153: ( 6):   1   3   9  17  51 153
154: ( 8):   1   2   7  11  14  22  77 154
155: ( 4):   1   5  31 155
156: (12):   1   2   3   4   6  12  13  26  39  52  78 156
157: ( 2):   1 157
158: ( 4):   1   2  79 158
159: ( 4):   1   3  53 159
160: (12):   1   2   4   5   8  10  16  20  32  40  80 160
161: ( 4):   1   7  23 161
162: (10):   1   2   3   6   9  18  27  54  81 162
163: ( 2):   1 163
164: ( 6):   1   2   4  41  82 164
165: ( 8):   1   3   5  11  15  33  55 165
166: ( 4):   1   2  83 166
167: ( 2):   1 167
168: (16):   1   2   3   4   6   7   8  12  14  21  24  28  42  56  84 168
169: ( 3):   1  13 169
170: ( 8):   1   2   5  10  17  34  85 170
171: ( 6):   1   3   9  19  57 171
172: ( 6):   1   2   4  43  86 172
173: ( 2):   1 173
174: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  29  58  87 174
175: ( 6):   1   5   7  25  35 175
176: (10):   1   2   4   8  11  16  22  44  88 176
177: ( 4):   1   3  59 177
178: ( 4):   1   2  89 178
179: ( 2):   1 179
180: (18):   1   2   3   4   5   6   9  10  12  15  18  20  30  36  45  60  90 180
181: ( 2):   1 181
182: ( 8):   1   2   7  13  14  26  91 182
183: ( 4):   1   3  61 183
184: ( 8):   1   2   4   8  23  46  92 184
185: ( 4):   1   5  37 185
186: ( 8):   1   2   3   6  31  62  93 186
187: ( 4):   1  11  17 187
188: ( 6):   1   2   4  47  94 188
189: ( 8):   1   3   7   9  21  27  63 189
190: ( 8):   1   2   5  10  19  38  95 190
191: ( 2):   1 191
192: (14):   1   2   3   4   6   8  12  16  24  32  48  64  96 192
193: ( 2):   1 193
194: ( 4):   1   2  97 194
195: ( 8):   1   3   5  13  15  39  65 195
196: ( 9):   1   2   4   7  14  28  49  98 196
197: ( 2):   1 197
198: (12):   1   2   3   6   9  11  18  22  33  66  99 198
199: ( 2):   1 199

Quantity with  1 factors is 1
Quantity with  2 factors is 46
Quantity with  3 factors is 6
Quantity with  4 factors is 59
Quantity with  5 factors is 2
Quantity with  6 factors is 27
Quantity with  7 factors is 1
Quantity with  8 factors is 31
Quantity with  9 factors is 3
Quantity with 10 factors is 5
Quantity with 12 factors is 13
Quantity with 14 factors is 1
Quantity with 15 factors is 1
Quantity with 16 factors is 2
Quantity with 18 factors is 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed two possibilities: $108=2^2\cdot 3^3$ and $198=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 11$.

Comment: Is there any general way?

Comment: I'm not aware of a better idea than what you did.

Answer (score 0):

A  general way.

**Hint**: Try use  the function $\tau(n)$ the number of divisors of $n.$

Comment: Do you have anything more specific in mind? We are trying to compute $\#\{n\leq 200:\tau(n)=12\}$, which is easier to write but doesn't seem to make the problem any easier.